# Keep getting Fatal error: Function name must be a string in

Tags: php, function

I'm not seeing anything quite like this but seems there's nothing defining  the  function here. I've tried what I can see but my PHP is limited at this  point-  only a month or so and I can't seem to get it:

> Error says: Fatal error: Function name must be a string  in
>   /home/ad67852/public_html/ft-adshot.com/login.php on line 35......

```
 }
 else
   {

   mysql_query("UPDATE members set lastlogin = '".time()."' where    userid='userid'");
    $_SESSION("ulogin");
    $_SESSION['ulogin'] = true;
    $_SESSION("uname");
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $userid;
    $_SESSION("pw");
    $_SESSION['pw'] = $password;
    //header("Location: /members/index.php");
```

I wondered if time () not defined or something but nothing I tried has worked so far!

Thanks in Advance I appreciate solving this one,
Robert

Comment: please align your question with correct format

Comment: I am sorry.But your code is difficult to read.Can you please give your full code.

Comment: That got me through Harshal -Thanks Much Ran into more after and was able to fix but would never have got there if this hadn't been past first !

Answer (score 0):

```
$time=time();
mysql_query("UPDATE members set `lastlogin` = '".$time."' where `userid`='userid'"); 
    $_SESSION['ulogin']; 
    $_SESSION['ulogin'] = true; 
    $_SESSION['uname']; 
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $userid; 
    $_SESSION['pw']; 
    $_SESSION['pw'] = $password; 
    //header("Location: /members/index.php");
```

use like this and try

Answer (score 0):

```
`$_SESSION("ulogin");` and `$_SESSION("uname");`
```

> Should replace with

`$_SESSION["uname"];  and $_SESSION["uname"]`

> because `$_SESSION` is array not function. See

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).